# Log in scope for an Azure DevOps REST API SPA app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I wrote a JavaScript SPA, reading and writing work item data through Azure DevOps REST APIs. I registered the app, and tried to use MSAL lib for the app.

When I was trying to log in (calling `msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest)`), I have no idea how to set the `scopes`:

```js
const loginRequest = {
  scopes: [],
};
```

I saw a lot of Microsoft docs and samples use **User.Read** as the example, but what about work items? I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes

But I still have no idea what to put in the `scopes` array. I tried `'vso.work_write'`:

```js
const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ['vso.work_write'],
};

msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
```

but when calling `loginPopup()`, the browser popped up the log in dialog box with error:

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> ServerError: invalid_client: AADSTS650053: The application 'Work item Manager' asked for scope 'vso.work_write' that
> doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
> Contact the app vendor.

Could you please give me some information on that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on "apparently it was incorrect"? What error message do you get? Does it occur at login, or when you try and use the work items REST API?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nick.McDermaid! I edited my question with more information.

Comment: I think the scope is correct but you probably need to explicitly grant it within the app registration. I had to do this to grant SQL Server access. Let me assure you, this whole app / entperprise registration process is VERY confusing. This might be a good 
 place to start. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis#add-a-scope

Comment: Going back and looking at how I added scopes to enable logging into Azure SQL, I'm finding the scope entries under "API Permissions" rather than "Expose an API" (as per the linked guide). I can see that it will allow Azure DevOps "user impersonation" which might give you all the scopes you need. You might want to try removing the scope altogether and trying to call the REST API to see what error message you get.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My situation is even more frustrating - I work in a big company and the IT dept controls everything. Every time I change the scopes, I'll need to ask their approval from the popped up log in dialog box. And they'll take a few days to discuss and respond. I found using `scopes: ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"]` would probably give me the full permission but I don't think IT will allow it. I have to apply for the scopes as little as possible :(

Comment: I feel your pain. Any development convenience or speed benefit cloud may have once given is now locked down. You can only get through these things by working constructively with the team.